# How to tell IntelliJ to use folder "web" instead of "webapp" for maven when building a war file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, intellij-idea

What I do is:

1. Create a new project with IntelliJ with Maven module.
2. Add Framework support to this project and pick: JSF.
3. Go to pom.xml and add: **packaging: war**.
4. And from Maven window in IntelliJ I click: Clean Install.

Well build fails, because maven is looking for a **webapp** directory instead of a directory called **web**. For building the project.

So, if I rename the folder **web** to **webapp** build goes fine.

However, I want to learn more about IntelliJ and maven, so I want to force maven to use the folder **web**. How can I properly do this

- Using the command line? I mean without invvolving IntelliJ at all?
- Using Intellij?

Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure this in the pom.xml file for your project.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>web</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html)

If IntelliJ behaves as expected, it should pick up this new configuration.

Comment: Is there a way to do make this change to the project template, so each time you create a new project it uses the modified configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this post](http://blog.miloszikic.com/2010/04/maven-war-plugin-and-non-default-webapp.html), which explains how to change the default `webapp` directory:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>web</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I will accept the other one, it is a minute earlier. Sorry. ( And he has less reputation.. ) And the reference link is a bit better. ( However you have the <build> tags.. But still. ) I hope you understand.

Comment: My bad, `webappDirectory` is used to change the default `target` directory... I have updated the answer accordingly.